# Table is not Dispalying on Output

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to display a table view using WPF. I don't have any issues with syntax. But when run it table is not displaying in on the screen

```
    <FlowDocumentReader>
        <FlowDocument>
            <Table CellSpacing="5">
                <Table.Columns>
                    <TableColumn/>
                    <TableColumn/>
                    <TableColumn/>
                    <TableColumn/>
                </Table.Columns>
                <TableRowGroup>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Paragraph>venu</Paragraph>  
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Paragraph>venu</Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Paragraph>venu</Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Paragraph>venu</Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableRowGroup>
            </Table>
        </FlowDocument>
    </FlowDocumentReader>
```

Code don't have any syntax errors. No table is displaying on the screen. Empty screen is displayig

Comment: It looked ok however I just tested it and it shows the table row. Maybe you should provide more context. Where and how you use the code? Check fonts and font color settings too.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the issue @BionicCode In my code i have included a few line regarding row definitions like the below         
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0*"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>                                                                               which is actually causing. when i edited or removed the code for height it is working fine